# Placing a button on an imageView at an absolute position

Tags: android, button, layout, imageview

I'm having trouble positioning a button on an image view.

I want to put a button on top of the image view, so that the button is "on" the image.

So far, I've put done it in a way, such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:orientation="vertical"   
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

 <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the button is added programatically when the app starts(at "onCreate"), so the button is shown on top of the image.

It works fine, but the problem is when I zoom/drag the image.

I want the button to move/zoom with the image, but with what I've got above, the button stays at a fixed position on a screen and only the image is being zoomed/dragged.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will depend on which element your button is relative to. Please post the complete xml code, knowing the properties of each view might be useful to find a solution.

Comment: @seiseises I edited the content with full xml. I set the image source and create&add the button to the relativeLayout from the code.

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the button, and what does your zooming/dragging code modify? Without viewing more code, my guess is that when you zoom/drag the image, you're just changing the size/position of the `ImageView`, and it's not affecting the `Button`. If that's the case, try wrapping both the image and the button in another layout, and making your zooming/dragging code affect that layout instead of just the image.